# play video containing transparency such that contents of window below can peek through?

Tags: windows-7, transparency, video-playback, chroma-key

I really like the 'flamethrower' effect the presenter adds while making an important point in [this video at 7:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWmMokA9JY&feature=youtu.be&t=470)

I asked him how he did it; he overlaid it in post-production.

I want to be able to do a similar effect while making an important point during ***live*** presentations.

I've searched and searched and found nothing so I'm trying here. Do you know of a way that a video (or even a gif) can be played on my Windows 7 PC such that the video (or gif) contains transparency, and will let the contents of the window below peek through? (Sort of how gif and png images can contain transparency and let the layer below peek through.)

Answer (score 0):

I found portable 3 apps, and one Google Chrome extension, that kind of let me do it.

- Desktop Destroyer / Stress Relief 2.0
- NetDisaster1.1
- desktoys
- Chrome Extension: Website Destroyer